# TypeError: Cannot read property "_rangeSliderData" of undefined

Tags: angular, plotly, typeerror, undefined

As I found, _rangeSliderData is property and put inside plotly.min.js. When I click again on this button (first click is not error) to update then updatePlot will be called along with this error message will be displayed on the console chrome. With the following code. How can I fix?

```
update() {
        if (!this.plotlyInstance) {
            const error = new Error(`Plotly component wasn't initialized`);
            throw error;
        }

        const layout = {...this.layout};

        return this.plotly.update(this.plotlyInstance, this.data, layout, this.config, this.frames).then(() => {
            const figure = this.createFigure();
            this.update.emit(figure);
        }, err => {
            console.error('Error while updating plot:', err);
            this.error.emit(err);
        });
    }
```

Because I've refered from the official document but it seems like quite less information for fixing this bug. So i hopefully can fix at here